# Error when I run "bucardo add database mybd"

Tags: centos6, postgresql, database-replication

This is the message error:

```
install_driver(Pg) failed: Can't locate DBD/Pg.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 9) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::Pg perl module hasn't been fully installed, or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Pg' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, Sponge, mysql. at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 308
```

Please could someone help me with this issue,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should install perl-DBD-Pg package

```
# yum provides "*/DBD/Pg.pm"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * epel: mirror.yandex.ru
 * extras: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: mirror.besthosting.ua
perl-DBD-Pg-2.15.1-4.el6_3.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL interface for perl
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DBD/Pg.pm
Filename    : /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Bundle/DBD/Pg.pm


# yum install perl-DBD-Pg
```

Comment: thanks it works. i hope that you could help me with this another problem
when i run "bucardo start"  i get this message:


Checking for existing processes Can't locate boolean.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Bucardo.pm line 34. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Bucardo.pm line 34. Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 833.